# visibility in pipes as a multithreaded messaging mechanism

Tags: c, multithreading, pipe, visibility

Let's say I have a few threads that can write to a pipe in equal sized chunks which are smaller than `PIPE_BUF`, this is atomic.

However I wonder if I read the pipe is it guaranteed that I either get nothing (pipe is empty) or I get a full sized chunk or more chunks?

so in practice I write chunks of 16 bytes from multiple threads to the pipe. is it guaranteed that the read only reads 0, 16, 32, 48 bytes and nothing inbetween. like 2, 5, 7, etc?

Comment: Do you surround read/write to pipe i/o with some sort of mutex? If not, then there is no guarantee of anything.

Comment: no, but that is the entire point of its atomicity, at least in regarding to writes

Comment: IIRC, the atomicity will prevent interleaved writes, but the read side is quite possibly free to return any fragment of what's been written that it decides to. Granted with a 16-byte size, that will probably align with most of the "usual" buffer sizes, so you might be ok. But it's probably not guaranteed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux man page for pipes (`man 7 pipes`) cites POSIX.1-2001 in saying writes of less than `PIPE_BUF` are atomic, but the same page makes no guarantees about reads.

You might be able to find something in the POSIX std itself for a written "guarantee".

In general, POSIX `read` should be assumed to be able to return less than requested length, so that's the safest thing to do here.  It also makes your code more maintainable if you ever switch to a socket, file, serial port, etc.

Alternatively, message queues (POSIX or SysV) might be what you're really after if you have control over both ends of this pipe and want message passing between threads with atomic read & write on both ends.